# Smart Card Reader (CAC) operation - what deauthorizes session?

Tags: smartcard, card-reader

We are planning to shock test a USB smartcard reader (CAC reader) for a DoD application, and need to know more about what indications to look for. Our only real concern is that the user remains logged in to the equipment during the event. Which brings us to the question - what is the mechanism that tells a computer that the session is no longer authorized or active? The manufacturer added a debounce circuit in response to their internal testing, and I assume it was merely for a "Card Present" switch. Is there a physical "CardPresent" switch or is it the physical contacts to the chip on the card that provides continuous authorization? Or is it both? In other words, once a card is inserted and the computer reads the chip and authorizes access, what is the mechanism that de-authorizes the session? Can I lose contact with the chip and remain authorized as long as the card is not removed? Am I asking the right questions? I expect to ask the OEM same questions, but would like a bit of background to know if I'm being bs'd or not.

Answer (score 0):

Basicy the card losses its login state when it loses power, is given an invalid PIN or a logout command is sent. Also if card is dual PIV/CAC, it may lose the login state when switching between PIV and CAC applets.

The application will then not be able to do a crypto operation until the PIN is sent again. But applications may cache the PIN so it can reconnect to the card and send the PIN without the user knowing what happened.

You say "logged in to the equipment" which I assume is different then the reader. So most likely the application and equipment only uses the card once at startup and allows the card to be removed or lose power. Unless the equipment is using the CAC card to do multiple signature or encryption operation in which case the card will need to stay powered up or PIN resent to card to login.

OpenSC https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wik  has a CAC driver, and debugging tools, so you could watch what is going on. I don't have a CAC card, but do have PIV and other smart cards.